# How do I access subclass attributes passed down from superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a subclass that extends from it's parent class and I'm having trouble understanding how I would access object attributes from the subclass that were inherited from the parent class.

In my example, I'll call the class `Friend` which inherits `name` and `phone` from `Acquaintance` but has it's own variables `birthdate` and `address`. Once that's created, I want to print the content of a `Friend` object which includes `name`, `phone`, `birthdate`, `address`.

Because I want my variables to all be private, I figured I would use getters, but I'm not sure how I would call the parent class in this case.

```
public class Acquaintance {

    private String name;
    private String phone;

    public Acquaintance(String name, String phone) {

        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void printContact() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name + ", Phone: " + this.phone);

    }

}
```

Subclass:

```
public class Friend extends Acquaintance {

    private String address;
    private String birthdate;

    public Friend(String name, String phone, String birthdate, String address) {
        super(name, phone);
        this.address = address;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public void printContact() {
        /* This is where I'm having trouble. 
        I don't know how to access the name, 
        and phone which are contained in the superclass.
        */


        System.out.println("Name: " + "Phone: " + "Birthdate: " + this.birthdate + "Address: " + this.address);
    }

}
```

Comment: Inherits also the methods. So, you can call getName() without any trouble.

Comment: `private` attributes are not inherited

Comment: this.getPhone()

Comment: Your code won't even compile. Your `getName` getter is marked static, and that means it can't access instance fields.

Comment: As a best practice you should add `@Override` annotation to `printContact` in the child class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters in your parent class `Acquaintance` such as `getName` are public so that they are visible to the sub class `Friend` in this case. So just merely use the getters like `getName` to access fields defined in the super class from within your subclass.

In your case first make the `getName` method an instance method by merely removing the `static` modifier. Then change the code like so,

```
public void printContact() {
    /*
     * This is where I'm having trouble. I don't know how to access the name, and
     * phone which are contained in the superclass.
     */
    getName();
}
```

Comment: How would I call `getName()` then? would it be something like `super.getName()`?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I'll call the class `Friend` which inherits `name` and `phone` from Acquaintance

Since `name` and `phone` are declared `private`, they are **not** inherited. A subclass only inherits `protected` and `public` fields and methods from its parent class. This means that you must call `getName()` in order to access this field. You can call it without an qualifier or you can call it with `this.getName()`. In a class `getName()` and `this.getName()` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A subclass inherits all *public* and *protected* members from it's super class. In your case, since `getName()` is public, you can normally call it in the subclasses of `Acquaintance`, like below:

```
public void printContact() {
    System.out.println("Name: " + this.getName() + "Phone: " + this.getPhone() + "Birthdate: " + this.birthdate + "Address: " + this.address);
}
```

Note that the use of the keyword `this` is optional. It merely "highlights" that it's the current object who is calling the method.

Also, when you want the children of a superclass to inherit it's members (variables, methods, etc) while still keeping them invisible to other classes, you can do as follows:

- Create an exclusive *package* for the superclass and it's children;
- If you want the members of the superclass to be accessible only by the children inside the *package*, declare them without an access modifier (*e.g.:* `int phone`);
- If you want the members of the superclass to be accessible by any of the children, declare them with the `protected` access modifier (*e.g.:* `protected int phone`);.